# How to save checkbox values for logged in users?

Tags: php, database, code

Hello~ How can I have checkboxes save their values for a logged in user?

My Wordpress website features various checklists in a table format. When a user finishes a task on the list, they would be able to tick one of the boxes to signify completion. That value should then be saved to the database, either automatically or by clicking a save button. When the user returns to that page later on, the boxes that they selected should remain.

[[Page Example]](https://trialsoffantasy.com/fashion-accessories/)

I only know how to insert a clickable HTML box, but that's the extent of my coding knowledge. (Although I'm not entirely sure what values to include in that HTML for saving purposes.)

`<input id="example" name="example[]" type="checkbox" value="example">`

How would I accomplish this? If you could go into a bit of detail, I'd really appreciate it, I'm a code newbie. n.n"